# Is it possible to make UICollectionViewCell span width of collectionView in portrait and landscape using only Interface Builder and AutoLayout

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout, xcode5.1

I realize that all this can be done in code in various manners adjusting the collectionView layout on device rotation or returning a different size in the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol method

`-(CGSize) collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`

I'm trying to accomplish this using only Interface Builder and auto layout if possible.  How do you pin the collectionView cell to the sides of the collectionView or accomplish this in another manner?

Here is an example of what I have currently:

[image: portrait]
[image: landscape]

You can see that in landscape, the cell is not spanning width of collectionview.

Comment: I don't think that's due to the collection view cell, but rather due to your collection view not having top-bottom-trailing-leading space set to 0.

Comment: @LordZsolt - I do have these set to 0 on the collectionView.

Comment: this seems like a good answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17598033/202064 which makes my question a duplicate